# Dagesh after an interrogative hey

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vayera

[Bereshit 18:21](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0118.htm#21)

> אֵֽרְדָה-נָּ֣א וְאֶרְאֶ֔ה הַכְּצַֽעֲקָתָ֛הּ הַבָּ֥אָה אֵלַ֖י עָשׂ֣וּ | כָּלָ֑ה וְאִם-לֹ֖א אֵדָֽעָה:‏
>
> I will go down now, and see whether they have done altogether according to the cry of it, which is come unto Me; and if not, I will know.'

הכצעקתה is a question, the hey is an interrogative form, so why is the khaf with a dagesh? Is it a dagesh Kal?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be?

Comment: @Doniel it usually doesn't השופט כל הארץ לא יעשה משפט? הגם לכבוש את המלכה עמי בבית? המן העץ אשר צויתיך לבלתי אכול ממנו אכלת? הבנהרים חרה יקוק? התשפט התשפט את עיר הדמים? הכזונה יעשה את אחותינו? הלא אצלת לי ברכה?

Answer (score 5):

The interrogative ה is usually vowelized with a chatef patach, however when it preceeds a sh'va then it is transformed to a patach.  In this instance, it doesn't change the strength of the kaf. Gesenius lists this form as an exception to the rule (it seems one of ten [Eze. 20:30](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1220.htm#30), [Gen. 17:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0117.htm#17), [37:32](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0137.htm#32), [Num. 13:19](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0413.htm#19), [Job 23:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2723.htm#6) etc.) Rashi, Radak, Ibn Ezra don't make any specific comment about this.  Perhaps they don't see it as interrogative.